# Stack program to enter names and reprint in C++

Tags: c++, string, stack

So this program that I have is a stack program that is to let a business owner enter the names of clients. I have an error on the loop where it's supposed to push names onto the stack, which I feel may have something to do with the fact that I used stoi. Any thoughts?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<string> name;

    cout << "Welcome to Carl's Cab Stand!!" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    string input;
    while (input != "Stop") //Loop to enter names
    {
        cout << "Enter the names of your clients for today (Enter 'Stop' when finished): " << endl;
        cin >> input;
    }

    int x = stoi(input); //Convert int/string

    for (int y = 0; y < x; x++) //Loop to push names onto stack
        name.push(y);

    while (!name.empty()) //Loop to print names
    {
        cout << name.top() << endl;
        name.pop();
    }

    cin.get();cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which error? Post the exact error message.

Comment: What do you think you are doing in the `while (input != "Stop") ...` loop?

Comment: Why `std::stack`? Just to explore how it works? The problem with that structure is you have to break it to use it.

Comment: Read your program out loud to yourself. "Read names until the input is "Stop", then convert that input to an integer 'x', and then add the integers from 0 to 'x' to the stack of names...".

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some bugs in your code.

In your while-loop you always overwrite the variable input with your latest input. And in your case it will always be "Stop".

Then if you use stoi, on the variable input with the value "Stop", what should it return?

It also seems that there are problems with the for loop: (int y = 0; y < x; x++)
you increment x with each iteration. so if x is positive it will run until an overflow will occure.
The error you will receive may happen because of this line:

name.push(y);

The stack is for strings. y is an integer. So I Thin this would lead to an error.

So check your program again and think about how it could work.

regards
Andi

Comment: So I turned the if loop into a while loop, but it didn't reprint the names:   
    while (input != "Stop") //Loop to push names onto stack
    {
        name.push(input);
    }

Comment: there is no "if loop". I think you mean that you have changed "for" to "while". Think about what your program should do. For example you could push name of your clients on the stack in the first loop. so read it from stdin and than push it to the stack......